# Upload images from Angular to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to upload an image from Angular frontend to NodeJS backend server.
I'm trying to use multer module in node, but I'm not getting the "req.file" parameter that would be given.

This is my form in Angular (updateProfile() sends the form to the node server):

```
<div class="container p-4">
    <form (submit)="updateProfile()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     ....
     <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="image" placeholder="Image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
                <img src={{user_details.image}} alt="Image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my node multer configuration file.

```
// Uploading images
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,cb) {
        cb(null, './src/public/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req,file,cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage});

module.exports = upload;
```

And this is the route in server where I should get the image submited in the frontend:

```
const img_upload = require('../helpers/img_upload'); // this is multer module

router.post('/update_profile', verifyToken, img_upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    const { name, first_surname, second_surname, age, birdth_date, location, phone, image } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body.image, req.file)
....
}
```

As you see, I'm using multer as middleware for uploading single image, but when I debug it is giving me an undefined req.file parameter.
[image]

Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you able to upload the image using postman/curl?

Comment: Do you have a repo we can check out?

Comment: I can create it now @RobertPerez

Comment: https://github.com/adrianrevilla009/MEAN-social_network @RobertPerez

Comment: Perfect, checking it out.

Comment: Since you're exporting upload and not img_upload. Could you change the import to be: 
const upload = require('../helpers/img_upload');
And also change the middleware function to upload.single('image')

Comment: This error solved, maibe I put it again when retrieving some changes. Did you try changing this code and it runs? @RobertPerez

Comment: No, I haven't been able to see the front-end code, maybe it didnt upload or something. I was only able to see the backend. 

Did that resolve your issue?

Comment: Let me know if you need further help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're exporting 'upload' and not 'img_upload'. Could you change the import to be: `const upload = require('../helpers/img_upload');` And also change the middleware function to `upload.single('image')`

Comment: Adding this to the answers because I believe you stated it worked.